# Can't access shared folder of win8/win7 machine - Error code: 0x80004005. Unspecified Error

Tags: windows-7, windows, network-shares, windows-8-preview, unc

It's ironic that I, software engineer with 12 years of experience, continue to have this problem from one version of Windows to another without being able to achive consistent result (sometimes it works).

Here it goes again.

I have a machine with Win8 Consumer Preview. It doesn't really matter that it's win8. I had same issue with win7 before. On given machine I created local admin user with same name and password I have on second PC (the machine I'm typing this from now).

I have two questions to you guys.

- Why I'm not able to access C$ share of win8 machine from another Win7 machine? I get error that C$ doesn't exist even though it does.
- Why I'm not able to access share named "test" in Win8 for which Permission set to Full for Everyone. When I attempt to access it from Win7 machine I'm asked to enter username and password. After entering local administrator credentials I get error "Windows cannot access \192.168.1.123\test. Error code: 0x80004005. Unspecified Error".

Windows Firewall is disabled on Win8 machine for both Private and Public networks. Guest account is disabled. Built-in admin account is enabled. Machine is pingable from other machines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Regedit to Create `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` Value

This is an extract from my account [of the access denied problem](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/win8/windows8-administrative-shares.htm)

Type `Regedit` in the Search dialog box, right-click the executable and `Run as administrator`.

Once Regedit launches navigate to this path:

> HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System

For a 32 bit system, create a new `DWORD` value called `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy`.  For a 64 bit system, make a `QWORD` (64-bit) called `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy`.

In either case, set the value to numeric `1` (meaning on), and remember to click `OK`.
Usually, the `LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy` value gets created before you have a chance to set the data value; no problem, just double-click and modify the data from `0` to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that all problems mentioned are connected with security.

Local administrator accounts on two different computers/systems even with same name and password are two different accounts.

"Everyone" must be an account known either locally on same computer if log on is on local computer **OR** account known on network if computer has joined network via network log on.

A network administrator and a local administrator are two different accounts with different rights.

Every account is unique being either local or a network account.
A local account with name and password is different from the account with same name and password on the network.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Any suggestions how to fix it ? What's puzzling to me is that I provide correct credentials when it asks me.